# .htaccess redirect 301: issue with multiple slashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to make some redirects in my website. I migrated from WP to Jekyll last year, so directories changed, specially about images location and categories.

First, I redirect from http to https. Then, from www to non-www. Then, I remove the `index.html`. Then, I remove multiple slashes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Finally, I do some specific 301 redirections. For example, this one:

`Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/2012 /`

The result is `domain/2012` instead of `domain`...

If I try to do something like this:

`Redirect 301 /wp-content/uploads/2012/ /`

The result is domain//

How can I fix this? Is this correct?

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# Remove www subdomain
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# Remove index.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
</ifModule>

# Remove multiple slashes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)/{2,}([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2 [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

## add https, remove www and index.html in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html[?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:index\.html)?$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

# remove multiple slashes from URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s[^?]*//
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]

# specific 301 redirects with optional trailing slash
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2012/?$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you completely clear your browser cache before testing this .htaccess on your local Apache.

Comment: Thanks! This works very well. Even I think that the loadtime of the website is faster, reducing the TTFB.

Comment: Ouch! 12 days later, Google Search Console returns a "Redirect Error" on "coverage". I'm not sure what I should fix, now.

Comment: Well, I think I fixed it. For https, www and index.html I'm using my old config. For multiple slashes and specific 301 redirects I'm using your code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your updates and great to know you have figured a way out.